# SQL Syntax: Casting a datatype that is stored as data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id    datatype        name    value
0     nvarchar(255)   myName  'Paul'
1     int             age     '30'
2     float(53)       Custom1  0.5
3     float(53)       Custom2  1.3
4     float(53)       Custom3  2.7
```

I am wondering if it is possible to do something like the following where I cast the order by as a float - I know this is incorrect syntax but wondering if this can be done.

```
SELECT datatype, name, value FROM myTable
ORDER BY (float)name
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a very poor design for a database table. You should not be doing this! You are going to have horrible problems with performance and querying. This is not a way a relational table should ever be used.  (ANd BTW float is a poor choice for a datatype in almost any conditions as it will give rounding errors in calculations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert datatypes in SQL you can use [CAST or CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
SELECT CAST('123' AS FLOAT), CONVERT(FLOAT, '123')
```

But if your name field contains a value that cannot be converted to a valid float, you'll get an error.

e.g.

```
SELECT CAST('NotAValidFloat' AS FLOAT)
```

will give you:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```